# How to evaluate if steatment for non-boolean objects with Pebble?

Tags: if-statement, casting, pebble

In original Twig implementation the `if` steatment accepts also objects, for example:

```
{% if myObj %}
```

or

```
{% if myObj.mySubProp %}
```

it will be converted to boolean true if the object is non-null/non-empty.

Is there any way to do it with Pebble instead of using "empty" keyword?
I need to use an existing twig templates set and I cannot refactor the entire template.